# IPython input prefilter

Tags: python, ipython

There are various [hooks](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.hooks.html) in IPython, but the one that interests me right now is `input_prefilter`.

From carefull IPython source inspection, I learned that it is not called anywhere. What is the other way to filter(or at least inspect) a next line that will be run, maybe through some shell state in other hooks like `pre_run_code_hook`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are interested by [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/inputtransforms.html). The input transformation has been reworked for 1.0 so the drop of `input_prefilter` might have been forgotten.